# PostgreSQL full text search abbreviations

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching, trigram

I created a Postgresql full text search using 'german'. How can I configer, that when I search for "Bezirk", lines containing "Bez." are also a match? (And vice-versa)

Comment: You need to create a custom [synonym dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) if you want to match it with text search

Comment: @pozs seems like your suggestion is the way to go. When you formulate it as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pozs is right. You need to use a [synonym dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY).

1 - In the directory $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data create the file german.syn with the following contents:

```
Bez Bezirk
```

2 - Execute the query:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY german_syn (
    template = synonym,
    synonyms = german);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION german_syn(COPY='simple');
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION german_syn
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart,
        word, hword, hword_part
    WITH german_syn, german_stem;
```

Now you can test it. Execute queries:

```sql
test=# SELECT to_tsvector('german_syn', 'Bezirk') @@ to_tsquery('german_syn', 'Bezirk & Bez');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

test=# SELECT to_tsvector('german_syn', 'Bez Bez.') @@ to_tsquery('german_syn', 'Bezirk');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Additional links:

1. <s>[PostgreSQL: A Full Text Search engine](http://shisaa.jp/postset/postgresql-full-text-search-part-1.html)</s> (expired)

Comment: Hi @Artur, how to use the COPY, is a full language copy?  `german` and `simple`  are languages....  PS: the link is not working

Comment: @PeterKrauss, can you show en example of your COPY query? PS: thanks, I marked the link as expired.

Comment: Hi, thanks the reply!  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60082663/287948

Answer (score 0):

Try using a wildcard in your search.

For example:

```
tableName.column LIKE 'Bez%'
```

The `%` will search for any letter or number after the `Bez`

Comment: The point is that "Bez." is stored in the database and I query for "Bezirk" so queries are the other way round than you assume and suggest.

Comment: The description of the problem is very vague and therefore it is difficult to determine exactly what you are trying to do.  Sorry I was not able to assist you.  Good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Description is very vague to understand what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you need simple [**pattern matching**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) search as you looking for abbreviations (so need to do stemming like in Full Text Search). I would with [**`pg_trgm`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) for this purpose:

```
WITH t(word) AS ( VALUES
  ('Bez'),
  ('Bezi'),
  ('Bezir')
)
SELECT word, similarity(word, 'Bezirk') AS similarity
FROM t
WHERE word % 'Bezirk'
ORDER BY similarity DESC;
```

Result:

```
 word  | similarity 
-------+------------
 Bezir |      0.625
 Bezi  |        0.5
 Bez   |      0.375
(3 rows)
```