# Synonym DICTIONARY for `simple` language is not working

Tags: postgresql, search, synonym

I am supposing that we can use [this old recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038277/287948) and only replace the language `german`  to language `simple` (that is the "no language")... But it is not working.

```sql
  CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_synonym (
     TEMPLATE = synonym,
     SYNONYMS = synonym_sample
     -- default /usr/share/postgresql/12/tsearch_data/synonym_sample.syn
  );
  CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_synonym(COPY='simple'); -- need it??
  ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_synonym
     ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, word, hword, hword_part
     WITH my_synonym   -- make sense??
  ;

 SELECT to_tsvector('my_synonym', 'Postgresql') 
      @@ to_tsquery('my_synonym', 'Postgresql'); -- true


    SELECT to_tsvector('my_synonym', 'Postgresql') 
         @@ to_tsquery('my_synonym', 'pgsql'); -- false. NOTICE:  
    -- text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
    SELECT to_tsvector('my_synonym', 'Postgresql pgsql') 
         @@ to_tsquery('my_synonym', 'pgsql'); -- false. Same NOTICE.
```

The `synonym_sample.syn`  is described in the current [Guide's 12.6.3. Synonym Dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) section. It converts "pgsql" abbreviation into "postgres"   word... So **many problems**

1. fail, not work, not translated "pgsql" into "postgres".
2. ignored  "pgsql" (!)
3. generates a NOTICE that not makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Once you are done doing synonym replacements, you need to pass the resulting lexemes along to a stemmer.  That occurs in both examples you link to, but does not occur in your example.  You can use "simple" as a dummy stemmer which just passes its output along without doing any actual stemming.

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_synonym
     ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, word, hword, hword_part
     WITH my_synonym, simple;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by @jjanes. You need to pass a result of your `synonym` dictionary to the `simple` dictionary.

Here is the results if you don't pass a result to the `simple` dictionary:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('my_synonym', 'Postgresql'), to_tsquery('my_synonym', 'pgsql');
 to_tsvector | to_tsquery
-------------+------------
 'pgsql':1   |
```

And here is the results if you pass it:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('my_synonym', 'Postgresql'), to_tsquery('my_synonym', 'pgsql');
 to_tsvector | to_tsquery
-------------+------------
 'pgsql':1   | 'pgsql'
```

But there is **another approach** in case if you don't want to use other dictionaries other than `synonym`. You can use `dict_xsyn` contrib module. Here is its documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dict-xsyn.html

Just do the following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dict_xsyn;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY xsyn(
    RULES='xsyn_sample', KEEPORIG=false, MATCHSYNONYMS=true);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION xsyn(COPY='simple');
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION xsyn
    ALTER MAPPING FOR
        asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, word, hword, hword_part
    WITH xsyn;
```

Here I don't use the `simple` dictionary. Creating `dict_xsyn` extension also creates the `xsyn` dictionary. But it doesn't create a configuration, so you need to create appropriate configuration.

You also need to configure the `xsyn` dictionary with appropriate options or to create new one. My `xsyn_sample.rules` file is:

```
supernova sn sne 1987a
postgresql pgsql
```

And here is the results:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('xsyn', 'Postgresql'), to_tsquery('xsyn', 'pgsql');
 to_tsvector | to_tsquery
-------------+------------
 'pgsql':1   | 'pgsql'
SELECT to_tsvector('xsyn', 'Postgresql') @@ to_tsquery('xsyn', 'pgsql');
 ?column?
----------
 t
```